# Tangent spaces to the orbit of a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G\subset GL(n)$ be a Lie subgroup and denote 
$$
M:=G x_0 = \{ Ax_0\ :\ A\in G\}\subset \mathbb R^n,$$
where $x_0\ne 0$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb R^n$. Then $M$ is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$.

> **Question**. Is it true that $$\tag{1}A(T_{x_0} M)=T_{Ax_0} M,\qquad \forall A\in G\ ?$$

---

At first sight I would say that (1) is true. However, if the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is given by
$$\mathfrak g = \text{span}\ (g_1, g_2\ldots g_m), $$ 
then 
$$T_{x_0} M = \text{span}\, (g_1 x_0, \ldots ,g_mx_0),$$
and analogously 
$$
T_{Ax_0} M=\text{span}\, (g_1 Ax_0, \ldots, g_mAx_0), $$
while 
$$
A(T_{x_0} M) = \text{span}\, (Ag_1 x_0, \ldots ,Ag_mx_0),$$
and I don't see a reason why the last two vector spaces should coincide. I don't know how to handle the commutators $[g_j, A]$, where $g_j\in\mathfrak g$ and $A\in G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restriction $f_A$ of the map $A$ to $M$ induces a diffeomorphism of $M$, remark $df_A=A$ since $A$ is linear.  We have $f_A(x_0)=A(x_0)$, and $df_A(T_{x_0}(M))=A(T_{x_0}M)=T_{f_A(x_0)}M=T_{A(x_0)}M$.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complement Tsemo's answer, which is short and elegant, with a couple commentaries.

Tsemo's argument shows that $T_{Ax_0} M = A(T_{x_0} M)$, that is 
$$\tag{1}
\text{span}\, ( g_1 A x_0, \ldots ,g_n Ax_0) = \text{span}\,(Ag_1 x_0,\ldots, Ag_n x_0).
$$
This identity can be proved directly, by observing that 
$$\tag{2}
A^{-1} g A \in \mathfrak g, \qquad \forall g\in\mathfrak g,\ \forall A\in G, $$
so, even if $g_jA\ne Ag_j$ in general, it is nonetheless true that $g_jA$ is a linear combination of $Ag_1,\ldots Ag_n$, and (1) follows from basic linear algebra.

Now, the identity (2) is a basic fact of abstract Lie group theory and it looks quite trivial. I have tried to prove (2) via the matrix exponential, that is, taking $A=e^{\lambda h}$ for a $h\in \mathfrak g$. Then (2) is equivalent to 
$$
\left(1-\lambda h +\frac{\lambda^2}{2}h^2 -\ldots\right) g \left(1+\lambda h +\frac{\lambda^2}{2} h^2+\ldots\right)\in \mathfrak g, $$
which looks much less obvious. I have computed some terms of the left-hand side; 
$$
g +\lambda(gh-hg)+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}(h^2g+gh^2-2hgh)+\ldots $$ 
and to my amazement I have discovered that they equal 
$$
g+\lambda [g, h] +\frac{\lambda^2}{2}[[g,h],h]+\ldots $$
which is in agreement with (2), since linear combinations of commutators in $\mathfrak g$ are in $\mathfrak g$. Indeed, this is the definition of Lie algebra.

The moral is that the modern viewpoint on Lie groups and Lie algebras is truly impressive, but it can also look a lot dryer than it actually is.